# How to uninstall jdk 12.0.1 from Mac OS?

Tags: java, java-12

I want to uninstall java version 12.0.1 on macbook pro.

I have installed java 12.0.1 but its not supported for my eclipse Kepler version..

I have tried by some commands in terminal but its all not workout.

**Could anyone help me to uninstall Java 12 ?**

Comment: How did you install it? And which vendor did you get it from: Oracle, Adopt OpenJDK, ...?

Comment: Why can't you just leave it and make java 6 (really?) the default version?

Comment: Not an answer for now, but for in the future, you can use SDKMAN to install multiple Java versions and easily switch between them. See https://sdkman.io/install

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By using this commands, can easily uninstall java from macOS.

```sh
java -version
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/*
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/Java*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/Java*
```

Run `java -version` again to confirm if java was successfully uninstalled.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: This will remove all java versions in the system but not only 12!